# Will Maven overwrite a manually patched jar in local Maven repo?

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project that works just fine.

In order to triage an issue, I manually patched a jar to add debug logging and then copied it to the local Maven repo directory.  I made subsequent changes to the jar file to add more debugging and did a `mvn install:install-file` since that seemed more "official".

Note that I did not change the coordinates at all (I know that artifacts are meant to be immutable, but I did not want to change pom.xmls).

My question is: when (if ever) will Maven overwrite this patched jar with the one in the remote Maven repository which is considered the source of truth?

Comment: Installing an artifact will overwrite the previously installed one. But why do you need to install it?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  Do you mean "why call install-file when you can just copy the jar directly into your repository directory"?Or do you mean "Why are you changing stuff in the maven repository"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only three scenarios in which that jar can be overwritten:

1. If you delete the jar from your local m2 repository, it will be downloaded from the remote repository the next time you build your maven project.
2. If you build your maven project with '-U' option. Doing this will force maven to update the dependencies from remote repository.
3. If you perform an mvn install on the same artifact(updated code) with the same version.

Comment: Thanks for enumerating the scenarios.  I thought maybe Maven did a checksum analysis every once in a while to determine if the artifact changed and act accordingly, but I guess since Maven artifacts are considered immutable, then there is no point to doing that.  Maybe snapshots behave differently.

Comment: Yes.The behavior I mentioned is applicable to static (non-snapshot) versions only. In case of snapshots, the update policy defines how often an artifact will be updated from remote repository. I would strongly recommend to NOT use snapshot version if you intend to keep the modified artifact in your local repo.

Comment: I have found that maven will re-download artifacts if you use a particular repository (manager) and then change to a different one. For example we use Nexus at work, but when I go home and mess around I change my settings.xml to point at my home Nexus instance (everyone has one, right?). This results in Maven re-downloading many artifacts because it considers that the same artifact from different repos to be different. You can see the additional meta data that it places in the `_remote.repositories` file associated with each artifact in your local `~/.m2/repository`.

Comment: That's interesting. I dont think I have tried that. Will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I noticed while setting up my own repository and switching between them (trying to get mirroring to work) that Maven re-downloaded a bunch of stuff that I was pretty sure it already had.  I also noticed that if I removed some of the repositories after a successful build, the next build would fail because dependencies could not be resolved.  This seemed wrong to me because I assumed once a build worked, Maven had all the bits to rebuild it offline (assuming nothing changes).  Is that nor right?

Comment: The reason the latter part fails is because of the presence of `_remote.repositories` file in your local m2 repository location. If you remove the repositories, you will need to delete the _remote.repositories file to make it work.

Comment: Is 3. also true, if the version is no SNAPSHOT? And if not, is there a way to force install overwrite non SNAPSHOT versions in the local repository?

Comment: Yes, 3 is also true for non-SNAPSHOT artifacts as long as (needless to say) group id, artifact id and version of the artifact being uploaded/installed matches the one that already exists in repository.